# Object seems to be deleted twice

Tags: c++, linked-list

Recently I tried to construct a circular linked list. I met a weird thing. It seems that my objects in the list are deleted twice but without giving errors. But I am not sure.
My node struct is defined as:

```
class Node
{
public:
    int i;
    inline Node(int);
    ~Node() {}

    Node *next;// point to the next node
};


Node::Node(int j):i(j), next(0)
{}
```

And inside my linked list, I have my append method for adding elements to the tail:

```
void SLList::append(Node* pnew)
{
    nElmts++;
    if(!last_)
    {
        last_ = pnew;
        last_->next = pnew;
    }
    else
    {
        pnew ->next = last_->next;
        last_ = last_->next = pnew;
    }
}
```

And also my removeHead method to delete the head:

```
void SLList::removeHead()
{
    nElmts--;
    if (!last_) //warning needed
    {
        abort();
    }
    Node* f = last_->next;
    if(last_ == f)
    {
        last_->next = 0;
        last_ = 0;
    }
    else
        last_->next = f->next;

    delete f;
}
```

The destructor of the list class:

```
~SLListBase()
 {
     clear();
 }
```

And:

```
inline void SLList::clear()
{
    while(nElmts)
    {
        removeHead();
    }
}
```

In my test run, I built three Node* objects and appended them into the list.

```
SLListBase list = SLListBase();

Node *newNode =new Node(1);
Node *newNode1 = new Node(2);
Node *newNode2 = new Node(3);

list.append(newNode);
list.append(newNode1);
list.append(newNode2);
```

It worked fine. And elements were added to the tail one by one. And later on I found that I accidentally remained the delete lines I used to keep.

```
delete newNode;
delete newNode1;
delete newNode2;
```

My question is: when the list went out of scope, it will be deleted and its destructor will be called. And inside its destructor it will try to delete its elements again by invoking removeHead as its number of element variable nElmts was not zero. How could that happen without errors? Can anyone help to have a look? Thanks.

Comment: _`delete f;`_ it's probably deleted twice, yes!

Comment: Anything to do with rule of three?

Comment: @Jerry _"Anything to do with rule of three?"_ Loads of.

Comment: Why is your test program creating Nodes?  Isn't that the responsibility of the linked list class?  What should be done is that you give the linked list the *data* to add -- let the linked list figure out node creation from the data given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Yes you are right. It's supposed to be the responsibility of the list. But at this moment I needed it to be outside. And it just ran through without any errors.

Comment: @Jerry So are you deleting nodes in both your test program *and* in the linked list implementation?  If so, then this "shared responsibility* is the reason for your double deletion issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes.  Obviously the three Node* objects were deleted in the test program as well as in the destructor of the list. Normally, I wouldn't do that. I just accidentally found the delete lines were still there (they should be deleted). And it went through wihout any errors.

Comment: @Jerry It's ok that you found the issue.  However, your linked list class destruction will *not* work if I give you the address of a Node on the stack.   `SLListBase list = SLListBase(); Node newNode(1); list.append(&newNode);`  Your destructor for list will erroneously try to call `delete` on that node.  That's why it makes no sense to have the responsibility of node creation outside the list class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Yes. That would be a serious problem. I didn't realize that. Thank you indeed. I have to modify it.